# Specific line of code is jumping to a GoTo section without being instructed to

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am writing a VBA to which identifies the last row of the used range on a lead sheet in the active workbook and cycles through a specified array of other sheets to extend all the formulas in the used range. It then compiles a message box which communicates the sheet name, last row (which should match for all sheets, and the value in the date column for the last row in that sheet (also should be the same for all). The message box helps highlight if anything looks wrong.

The problem is occurring when the worksheet does in fact exist, and the code continues with assigning the last row variables. There is a specific line of code which, after executing, is causing the VBA to jump to a named section (SkipSheet) despite no instruction for this being given.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
    ' Loop through target sheets
    For Each TS In TSs
        ' Try to set the target sheet
        On Error GoTo SkipSheet
        Set ws = AW.Sheets(TS)

                ' Find the column number where 'Date' appears in row 3
                Dim dateColumn As Long
                dateColumn = Application.Match("Date", ws.Rows(3), 0)
                
                ' Check if 'Date' is found in row 3
                If IsError(dateColumn) Then
                    lastRowTS = "Date column not found"
                    Else
                ' Get the last row of the target sheet in the determined column
                    lastRowTS = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dateColumn).End(xlUp).Row
                    lastRowVL = ws.Cells(lastRowTS, dateColumn).Value
                End If
            
                ' Extend formulas to the last row of the lead sheet
                ws.Rows(lastRowTS & ":" & lastRowMD).FillDown
                RTN = RTN & TS & " = " & lastRowTS & " - " & lastRowVL & vbCrLf
            
NextSheet:
    Next TS
    GoTo EndOfSheets
    
SkipSheet:
    Set ws = Nothing
    RTN = RTN & TS & " = No Sheet" & vbCrLf
    Resume NextSheet
   
EndOfSheets:
    ' Display the message box
    MsgBox RTN
```

The unexpected jump occurs after the below line:
ws.Rows(lastRowTS & ":" & lastRowMD).FillDown

This is causing the RTN variable to not be set which screws up the final message box giving false negatives.

I have tried adding an additional IF condition to contain the "ws.Rows(..." lineand the "RTN =" line as shown below, but the issue persists, jumping to SkipSheet following ws.Rows:

```
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
                ' Find the column number where 'Date' appears in row 3
                Dim dateColumn As Long
                dateColumn = Application.Match("Date", ws.Rows(3), 0)
                
                ' Check if 'Date' is found in row 3
                If IsError(dateColumn) Then
                    lastRowTS = "Date column not found"
                    Else
                ' Get the last row of the target sheet in the determined column
                    lastRowTS = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, dateColumn).End(xlUp).Row
                    lastRowVL = ws.Cells(lastRowTS, dateColumn).Value
                End If
            
                ' Extend formulas to the last row of the lead sheet
                ws.Rows(lastRowTS & ":" & lastRowMD).FillDown
                RTN = RTN & TS & " = " & lastRowTS & " - " & lastRowVL & vbCrLf
            Else
                GoTo SkipSheet
            End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have absolutely no idea what's going wrong! If I've missed out any required information please let me know.

Comment: That will error if `lastRowTS` is a string. Where is `lastRowMD` assigned a value?

Comment: I don't think it's generally recommended to use lots of Gotos.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid the `GOTO` logic.

Instead use a `try`-method like this:

```vb
Public Function tryGetWS(strName As String, wb As Workbook, _ 
                         ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(strName)
    If Err = 0 Then tryGetWS = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

If worksheet exists the function returns `true` **and** the worksheet itself.

You can then can use it like this:

```vb
Sub test()
Dim TSs As Variant: TSs = Array("a", "b", "Tabelle1")

Dim TS As Variant, ws As Worksheet
For Each TS In TSs
    If tryGetWS(CStr(TS), ThisWorkbook, ws) = True Then
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    Else
        Debug.Print TS & " not found"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Another advantage of this method: It is clear what the function does - without reading the code itself :-)